# Can implement ECDSA and ECDH like algorithm in CoAP with the help of californium?

Tags: java, eclipse, coap, californium, ecdhe

I am working on [CoAP](http://coap.technology/) implementation for my academics, I am trying to integrate combined version of ECDSA and ECDH like algorithm in CoAP and will observe behavior of protocol after implementation. Till now I have gone through [Eclipse Californium is a Java implementation of CoAP](https://github.com/eclipse/californium). But still I am unclear about where to start and how to implement my combined version of algorithm in CoAP. Though following need to keep in mind for suggestions.

- Java and Eclipse based approach only.
- No simulation based implementation like as tinyOS,openWSN.

Any help,tutorial link will be appreciated.
I already followed CoAP Tutorial for Eclipse

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if it is exactly what you need, but currently there is a Scandium project which is a [DTLS](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6347) implementation for Californium.

https://github.com/eclipse/californium/tree/master/scandium-core

You may find something useful there.